# Is it spiritually safe to look at eclipse?

Tags: astrology, eclipse, omens

Is it spiritually safe to be outside during a solar or lunar eclipse? Is it okay to look at the Sun or Moon during an eclipse?

I know that it's not physically safe to look at the Sun during an eclipse, but I'm talking about spiritual safety.

I am assuming that it is spiritually safe to do so, however I need confirmation.

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. But I wouldn't recommend looking at a solar eclipse without eye protection at all.

Comment: Acc to my Guru it isn't safe due to certain harmful vibrations that occur during that time.We are advised to stay indoors, not eat/drink anything till the period gets over and do as much sadhana as possible during that period(reason is something along the lines that sadhana done during this period yields 4x benefit of the total sadhana done by you till now....)

Comment: @Rāmachandra I asked one of the priests at my temple and he said that I could go outside during an eclipse (but not eat food).